# 'numpy.int64' object has no attribute 'count' - error for plotting graph in python

Tags: python, numpy, plot, graph

​

```
plans = plans[plans.long_term_contract == 0].count()
plans = plans[plans.long_term_contract == 0].count()
```

> AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
>    in 
>   ----> 1 plans = plans[plans.long_term_contract == 0].count()
>   AttributeError: 'numpy.int64' object has no attribute 'count'

I want to display graph and first I want to count value with value 0 and value 1 and later display graph for both variables. I got this error. How can I count values in numpy array?

Comment: Could you please add a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? Notice that it is saying that your object is of type `numpy.int64`, not array.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `numpy.count_nonzero`.

E.g. suppose you want to get the number of `3`'s in a given array `arr`:

```py
arr = array([[1, 2, 7, 3],
             [3, 9, 0, 4]])
np.count_nonzero(arr==3)
```

the output will be:

```
2
```